# Reset the count to 0 after the following scenario

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with records as follows: Its just a sample table for understanding the scenario.

```
Create table resetcount
(
userid int,
totalhighprtjobs int,
[date] datetime
)


insert into resetcount Values (147,0,GETDATE())  
insert into resetcount Values (169,1,GETDATE())    
insert into resetcount Values (176,0,GETDATE())  
insert into resetcount Values (187,1,GETDATE())  
insert into resetcount Values (188,1,GETDATE())
```

Everytime when i assign a job to a userid the totalhighprtjobs gets increased by 1.it will assign to all the users randomly and equally. Suppose if all the count of totalhighprtjpbs becomes 1 then i want to reset all those to 0.if suppose today there are 3 jobs assigned to useids 169,187,188.tomorrow while assigning jobs since the count of highprtjobs of userid 147 and 176 are 0 first these two will be assigned a job.After assigning to these two the count ot totalhighprtjobs wil be 1 for all,then i want to reset the count to 0 for all after assigning to those two.

Can you guide me in this ..

Comment: Have you made a start on implementing this? What part(s) are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this .

```
  BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @Total INT


SET @Total = ( SELECT   COUNT(userid)
               FROM     resetcount WHERE totalhighprtjobs =1    
             ) ;

IF ( @Total = 0 ) 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE  resetcount
        SET     totalhighprtjobs = 0 

    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  resetcount
        SET     totalhighprtjobs = 1
        WHERE   userid  IN ( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                                        userid
                                FROM    resetcount
                                WHERE   totalhighprtjobs = 0 )
    END
    SELECT * FROM resetcount

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: if you want to ensure randomness, you can also add ORDER BY NEWID() to the subquery in the update statement.